# var/importexport cannot be used with directory pub/media/

Tags: magento2, import

I have a problem with import/export products. When i select entity type = "Product", select my .scv file and click "Start Import". System show me error like in the picutre below.
In exception.log

`main.CRITICAL: Path "/var/www/html/mytheme/var/importexport//file.csv" cannot be used with directory "/var/www/html/mytheme/pub/media/" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\ValidatorException(code: 0): Path \"/var/www/html/mytheme/var/importexport//file.csv\" cannot be used with directory \"/var/www/html/mytheme/pub/media/\" at /var/www/html/mytheme/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/PathValidator.php:63)"} []`

[image]

I found this soultion
[Import/Export cannot be used with directory](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323519/import-export-cannot-be-used-with-directory)
But it's not good for me because I have beta and production version, and in beta version import/export works well without any changes but in production i have this error. I was looking for differences between beta and production version but i have not found. Please help me.

Comment: I have same issue, Can you please share solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give 777 permission to `/var/www/html/mytheme/var/` and `/var/www/html/mytheme/var/importexport/` folder.

by

`sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/mytheme/var/` and `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/mytheme/var/importexport/`

Comment: Thanks for answear. I execute this command and it's not working. The same error is show :(

Comment: is there folder name locate under /var/www/html/mytheme/var/ like 'import_history' ,'import','export' . If not then create this and flush cache,give permission to pub,var,and generated also.

Comment: I have created export, import, import_history, importexport catalogs. I've granted permission 777 -R for var and pub folder still the same error :(

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try it . find your php.ini file;
find the “upload_max_filesize” parameter (additionally, check ‘post_max_size’ too);
replace the existing value with a bigger one;
restart your MySQL and Apache server;
reload import page

Comment: It's not working too ;(